# Modifying WPF UI objects stops execution

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

This is bugging me, but the reality is this. If I try to **modify a UI element**, or navigating through pages of my WPF application, **the following lines of code won't be executed**.

The code follows, but let me help you undestand that. The page makes a picture with the Kinect, and the user selects one of two possible images in overlay, then pushes a button to start a countdown. With this I hide every UI element.

After the countdown, I take a picture. Hopefully, I want a back button to go back to the menu, so after taking the picture I *make the UI element visible again*.

If I execute for instance `back_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;`, all the remaining lines of code will not be executed.

I am at loss here, really. I cannot spot the error, but I am not more than a newbie in this.

I hope you can help me!

Here's the C# code and the relative XAML file.

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Wpf;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Wpf.Controls;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Timers;
using ScreenShotDemo;

namespace FromScratch
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class pagePhoto : Page
    {
        private ColorFrameReader colorFrameReader = null;
        private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap = null;
        private BitmapImage overlay = null;
        private int countdown = 10;
        private System.Timers.Timer countdowntimer = null;

        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colorBitmap;
            }
        }

        public pagePhoto()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // open the reader for the color frames
            this.colorFrameReader = KinectSensor.GetDefault().ColorFrameSource.OpenReader();

            // wire handler for frame arrival
            this.colorFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_ColorFrameArrived;

            // create the colorFrameDescription from the ColorFrameSource using Bgra format
            FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = KinectSensor.GetDefault().ColorFrameSource.CreateFrameDescription(ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

            // create the bitmap to display
            this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorFrameDescription.Width, colorFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

            // use the window object as the view model in this simple example
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void back__Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new pageMenu());
        }

        // Actually start the selfie
        public void start_pic(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            male_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            female_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            back_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            zoomer_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            images_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            var p = sender as Button;

            if (p == male_)
            {
                overlay = new BitmapImage(new Uri("c:\\...\\m.png"));
            }
            else
            {
                overlay = new BitmapImage(new Uri("c:\\...\\f.png"));
            }


            imageView_.Source = overlay;
        }

        public void timer_tick(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (countdown == 1)
            {
                countdowntimer.AutoReset = false;
                countdowntimer.Enabled = false;
                countdowntimer.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> TAKE PICTURE " + countdown.ToString());

                doScreenshot(null, null);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> BEEP " + countdown.ToString());

                System.Media.SoundPlayer p = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("c:\\...\\beep-01a.wav");

                p.Play();

                countdown = countdown - 1;
            }
        }

        public void doScreenshot(object o, EventArgs sender)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> SCREENSHOT");

            // 
            // IF TRUE THE NEXT LINES WILL BE ***NEVER*** EXECUTED
            //
            if (false)
            {
                zoomer_.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
                zoomer_.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
            }

            // Screenshot
            if (this.colorBitmap != null)
            {
                ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();

                string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss"); //, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

                // capture entire screen, and save it to a file
                sc.CaptureScreenToFile("c:\\...\\SCREENSHOTS\\ScreenShot-" + time + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }

            // 
            // IF TRUE THE NEXT LINES WILL BE ***NEVER*** EXECUTED
            //
            if (true)
            {
                back_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

                // THE SAME GOES IF I TRY NAVIGATING
                //this.NavigationService.Navigate(new pageMenu());
            }

            System.Media.SoundPlayer p = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("c:\\...\\camera-shutter-click-01.wav");

            p.Play();
            Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> SCREENSHOT END");
        }

        private void closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.colorFrameReader != null)
            {
                // ColorFrameReder is IDisposable
                this.colorFrameReader.Dispose();
                this.colorFrameReader = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the color frame data arriving from the sensor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void Reader_ColorFrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // THIS CODE IS IRRELEVANT AND IT WORKS PERFECTLY
        }

        private void images__Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> START UP");

            images_.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.None;

            countdown = 5;

            countdowntimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            countdowntimer.AutoReset = true;
            countdowntimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_tick);
            countdowntimer.Enabled = true;

            countdowntimer.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Page x:Class="FromScratch.pagePhoto"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2014"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1000"
    Title="Page1">

    <Grid>

        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </Viewbox>
        <Button x:Name="back_" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="95" Height="95" Click="back__Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="c:\\...\\back.png" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="male_" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="300" Height="300" Click="start_pic">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="c:\\...\\m.png" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="female_" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="300" Height="300" Click="start_pic">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="c:\\...\\f.png" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

        <ScrollViewer Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                k:KinectRegion.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True" 
                k:KinectRegion.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
                k:KinectRegion.ZoomMode="Enabled" 
                x:Name="zoomer_"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                >
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="imageView_" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Name="images_" Visibility="Hidden" Content="PHOTO" Margin="0,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="134" FontFamily="Cinzel" FontSize="48" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#54FF0000" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Click="images__Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Timer executes its Tick callback function in a thread that's not the Dispatcher thread. zoomer_.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility being an UI element owned by the Dispatcher thread, this will raise an exception.

Wrap those lines in a Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't expect this behavior for timers!

Comment: Depends on timer you use. You can use DispatcherTimer to execute the callback directly in the Dispatcher thread. You can also use the System.Forms.Timers.Timer

Answer (score 0):

Have you stepped over the code in the debugger and ensured that an exception is not being thrown? Specifically on the line

```
sc.CaptureScreenToFile("c:\\...\\SCREENSHOTS\\ScreenShot-" + time + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

If an exception is throw there, the rest of the code may not execute, causing the visibility to never be set and the code to not be run.

Also your If(false) lines of code will never be executed, so there's no point in them being there.

Comment: The `if(false)` is there to take a screenshot, otherwise I won't have a file here. No exception is thrown by the `CaptureScreenToFile` call. The problem is that if I enable that `if(false)` nothing gets past that.